# Just starting Android Studio, I need guidance

Tags: android

I just decided today that I wanted to make a gallery app for my phone, pretty much just combine several features I like from different apps I've tried into one, perfect app, for me. The problem however is that although I know some java, took Programming 1 & 2 and currently taking AP Computer Science in high school, I have no idea where to begin. I roughly know and even less so understand the layout of Android Studio, but I can get by. I need help finding useful resources online to help me learn or even someone who is able to answer the probably many questions I have. I've watched some youtube videos and tried reading some tutorials but I haven't found anything that clears things up for me. I will ask a few questions now:

1.) I have no idea where to start or what to use to get the app to show images from device storage and micro sd card in a grid view. I have read things about using the RecyclerView to not use as much resources, and also something about Glide for better performance(I think thats what both those do, if I understand correctly) but I have no idea what to do with either or even how to use either.

2.) In the xml design portion I'm not good at navigating everything and understanding what I should use for what. I can make a good design in photoshop or other programs but I'm not sure how to actually take that vision and translate it into working pieces.

3.) Pretty much I just need help and will probably think of more questions as someone tries to answer those.

Thanks!

Comment: I would just suggest spending some more time researching. Your questions are too broad right now. Maybe try taking a look at some [open source gallery apps](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+gallery&type=Repositories) to help get a better idea.

Comment: I mean it's broad because I have no idea what I'm doing. I looked through some of those app's code and not understanding how android references things it didn't help much. Like for example, I couldn't figure out what thing to look at to know what lines of code allows the app to display the images from your device as thumbnails.

Comment: First thing first, [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/) is a nice detailed tutorial for gallery app and additionally, they've provided what to do for thumbnails (using Picasso for caching data to load fast and update on newly added items).

Comment: Secondly, XML designing is easy if you ignore the design view and works with code view as code view may seem harder but it's actually better, and you can export PNGs from photoshop to it and use `ImageViews` to put those PNGs on the app.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar I must be really bad at following tutorials because I'm doing what that says and I'm getting errors, as well as not understanding what I'm doing.

Comment: I think you should first learn the basics instead of copying code from random websites. BTW  I typed so long and then deleted it. Try [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-android-masterclass-learn-android-from-scratch/learn/v4/overview), this website is great for online courses (NOT PROMOTING, just experience), [this](https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-android-masterclass-learn-android-from-scratch/learn/v4/overview)  is the course I've taken and [this](http://bestblackhatforum.com/Forum-Udemy-100-FREE-for-LIMITED-TIME) is where you can get free coupons for courses of Udemy.

Comment: Anything I can help in, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good, free tutorials on the net. For example on the official Android Developer site: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html
 - where you can find a lot of useful example code snippets, but there are other sites also - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm . It starts with the very basics and has lots of examples too.

Other non-free tutorials can be found at

- udacity.com - Android Developer Nanodegree by Google
- udemy.com

To reach data from your device storage or from your micro SD card you have to understand the principle working of content providers.

I do not recommend Recycle View, when you are a beginner, because it is a more complex thing than a List View (or Grid View). Start with these and then upgrade.

Glide is cool thing, because it saves you from a lot of useless coding and easy to use. On their GitHub page you find detailed instructions how to import it to your project - I recommend Gradle - and how to use it.

In my point of view, start reading one of the free sites patiently and than you are going to get answer for your questions, but it is very important to understand the basics.

I hope I helped! Sorry for my bad English, I used it a long time ago.

Comment: maybe I'm just not in the right mindset to learn this, but it's not sticking and im not comprehending. I think I need more of a 1 on 1 experience rather than just reading or watching videos. at least until i understand basics.